# How to iterate Unicode characters? (Not codepoints)

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I'd like to iterate through Unicode characters, gobbling up all combining characters that follow the initial code point.

This is what I have so far, but it acts really weird for some random Unicode sequences I tried: (for example, when I pass it things like "a̔" (U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A followed by U+0314 COMBINING REVERSED COMMA ABOVE) it sees it as two characters rather than one. Other things, like "e︠" (U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E followed by  U+FE20 COMBINING LIGATURE LEFT HALF) are seen as one character)

```c
int COMBINING[] = {
    0x0300, 0x036F,
    0x1DC0, 0x1DFF,
    0x20D0, 0x20FF,
    0xFE20, 0xFE2F,
    0 //sentinel
};

utf8_index_t ut_nextchar(utf8_t source, utf8_index_t curr)
{
    int c = decode_cp(source, &curr);
    int comb = 0;
    if (c == 0)
        return -1;
    while (COMBINING[comb] != 0)
    {
        for (comb = 0; COMBINING[comb] != 0; comb += 2)
        {
            if (c >= COMBINING[comb] && c <= COMBINING[comb + 1])
            {
                c = decode_cp(source, &curr);
                if (c == 0)
                    return -1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return curr;
}
```

Comment: What library is this (the `utf8_t`, `utf8_index_t`, `decode_cp`)? Can you use ICU?

Comment: "it sees it as two characters rather than one". Because they are two characters. You are thinking of graphemes.

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified: I'm writing a small unicode-handling library, mostly to learn more about unicode. And I guess I'm talking about graphemes, because I think it is useful to treat them as atomic units of text.

Comment: Actually, treating a base character and combining character as a single atomic unit of text (e.g. for backspace purposes) is extremely harmful to users of most languages that *require* combining characters. The only people it helps are users of accented latin characters who are for some odd reason using the decomposed form when they want to treat accented letters as atomic...

Comment: On the other hand, you probably need to treat them as atomic units for the purpose of left/right arrow keys, delete key, text hilighting, etc.

Comment: Hm, since I'm writing a library, that probably means I should support both iterating over code points and over grapheme clusters, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Unicode characters are mostly 1:1 to Unicode codepoints - what you're interested in are Unicode grapheme clusters, which correspond to so-called user-perceived characters.

You can find my implementation of [the algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#GB1), including [property data](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/auxiliary/GraphemeBreakProperty.txt), [here at bitbucket](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/cggaertner/libtcu/downloads/gcbreak.h).

If you're not interested in the full algorithm, you can use

```
gc_break_property(c) == GC_BP_Extend
```

to check for characters with property *Grapheme_Extend* and

```
gc_break_property(c) & GC_FLAG_POSTFIX
```

if you want to include spacing marks as well.